# calculating first and fundamental form coefficients with surface normal and Gaussian curvature

Tags: surfaces, curvature, tangent-line, fundamental-solution, point-cloud

I have some points (point cloud), I need first and second fundamental form coefficients at each point.

before I used some polynomial surface fitting algorithm then these coefficients were calculated. but results aren't good because you know all fitting algorithm have error because number of points for fitting is n't enough.

I can calculate surface normal and gaussain curvature at each point (with PCL libarary) is there any way to calculate the coefficients with surface normal, gaussian curvature and maybe tangent plane without using surface fitting??

how I can calculate them.

Thanks a lot for your help.